# How to run a function in loop over the chunks of a list?

Tags: python, list, split, list-comprehension, chunks

I have a list of length 4700 of type string. First I made the list into equal chunks of size 1500. So now, I've 4 lists.

```
list_with_chunks = [[a,b,c,...],[f,g,h,....],[x,y,z,...],...,[l,m,n,...]]
new_list = []

def function():
 # dummy function
 return 2*x
```

I want a function which could use the above `function()` and pass the first chunk of `list_with_chunks` and append the result to `new_list` and then take the second chunk and append the result to `new_list` from wherever the previous appending stopped due to first chunk and so on until I finish passing all the chunks.

Update: Desired output:

```
new_list = [2*a, 2*b, 2*c.....,2*z] # all the chunks in just one final list.
```

Please help, TIA!

Comment: show the desired output

Comment: @Umair I've updated the question. Please check!

Comment: So if `list_with_chunks` were `[["A","B"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","H"]]`, the result would be `["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH"]`?

Comment: `4700 != n*1500` where n in Z

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, exactly.

Comment: @jarmod the last chunk is not equal in size. You'd get only 200 values in the last chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the chunks, use a list comprehension to multiple all the chunk elements, and use `extend` to append the result to the new list.

```
def function(new_list, list_of_lists):
    for l in list_of_lists:
        new_list.extend([2 * x for x in l])

function(new_list, list_with_chunks)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really helpful for a beginner.

Comment: What if I want to call some other complex function over the values inside `list_with_chunks`  instead of simple `2*x` ?

Comment: `some_complex_function(x) for x in l`